# Cakephp - get user id in controller when using Auth

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

It seems like a two-step process to get this,

```
    $u = $this->Auth->user();
    $uid = $u['User']['id'];
```

Isn't there a variable set somewhere once a user is logged in?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `$uid = $this->Auth->user('id');`

Check the api documentation: https://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-AuthComponent.html#_user

For everybody using the newer Cakephp v4.x: https://api.cakephp.org/4.4/class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#user()

Comment: The fact that you can supply a key arg is right there in the API... I think I'll take a look in there more often.

Comment: I get `Notice: Notice (1024): Undefined property: MyController::$Auth`

Comment: API link is also dead: 404

Answer (score 18):

In CakePHP there are several ways to get the user id from the session, here are a few examples

**To get the session user id within the controller use:**

```
$uid = $this->Auth->User('user_id');
```

**To get the session user id within a view, use: ( Not Recommended, I would set this in the controller)**

```
$uid = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
```

**To get the session user id within a model, use: (Not Recommended, but a solution)**

```
$uid = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');
```

**I don't recommend the above to get the session user id from within the model, I would pass it via the controller, use:**

```
$this->Model->function($uid);
```

**You can also get the session user id via pure php, use: (Althought using Cake you should stick with the conventions)**

```
$uid = $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'];
```

And there are more approaches, this is just a few...

Comment: This was a great answer and this should be the marked as the Accepted Answer

Comment: +1 for recommendation on passing from controller to model, instead of calling `CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');` in model.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$this->Auth->user('id')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also get the user details from the session if the Auth class is not available to you.

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
```

Comment: This is helpful if you don't have the AuthComponent registered at the AppController level

Answer (score 5):

**CakePhp 2.x:**

Anywhere:

```
AuthComponent::user('id')
```

Inside a controller:

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

Answer (score 5):

Even this question being posted way before present version, I'm gonna answer how to do it in Cakephp v4.x, because I just needed it and got a hard time finding this info, and it may be useful to someone else.

```
$identity = $this->request->getAttribute('authentication')->getIdentity();
```

Now, you have an `IdentityInterface` ORM-like object, which returns values from pairs named after the DB table you're using to track users. So, you can get all info from your DB, like:

```
$identity['email']
$identity['full_name']
$identity['id']
// etc
```

Comment: "you kinda show you're not using version 4.x"... did you see the date of the question? ;-)

Comment: OMG, no, I didn't! LOL! Thanks. Just edited my answer.

Comment: Yes! Spent hours searching for this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm that someone. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`$this->Session` is deprecated, as Simon says above, but now `$this->request->session();` is also deprecated.
For now, as August 2021 and CakePhp 4 the correct answer is:

```
$this->request->getSession()->read('User.id');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be of no use, but I was having a error cause by `$this->Auth->user();` This problem was solved using this instead.  I am not sure of the route of the issue, but it came up when calling a function from a Model in the same action as I used `$this->Auth->user();`
Using `AuthComponent::user('id')` solved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->Session` is deprecated

Use something like this

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$user_id = $session->read('Auth.User.id');
```